# How can I use static objects in my step definition classes? Or how can I retrieve PageFactory WebElements without getters?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, page-factory

I have two problems. One is that I do not understand how to correctly map static routes to my PageFactory Page WebElements. They work initially on my first scenario and then subsequent scenarios throw 
`'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException' exceptions. Cannot evaluate com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.toString()`

I believe the issue is that Cucumber is re-instantiating the Controller and the static WebElements are not being constructed.

***I realize I am not supposed to have static WebElements in a Page initialized by the PageFactory but it works for my first test scenario.

My question why do my static PageFactory WebElements work and how can I make them continue to work by constructing Step Definition classes that do not re-instantiate my the arguments passed inside?

Lots of research. I don't see any example of Pagefactory WebElements being retrieved without calling getters methods specific to those web elements.

Extended PicoFactory from the Controller hoping that the cucumber magic would somehow not re-instantiate my controller.

Controller

```
public class Controller {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    public Controller() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    /**Pages**/
    public Page getPage() { return PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), Page.class); }

    public void openURL(String str){
        driver.get(str);
    }

}
```

Page

```
public class Page {

    @FindBy(xpath= "//input")
    private static WebElement input;

    public enum Alias {
        INPUT(input);

        WebElement webElement;

        Alias(WebElement string) {
            this.webElement = string;
        }

        public WebElement getWebElement() {
            return webElement;
        }

    }

    public WebElement getWebElement(String str) {
        Alias alias = Alias.valueOf(str);
        return alias.getWebElement();
    }

}
```

Cucumber Step-Definition Class

```
public class StepLibrary {

    private Controller controller ;
    private Page page;

    public StepLibrary(Controller controller) {
        this.controller= controller ;
        page = controller.Page();
    }

    @Given("^Whatever$")
    public void whatever() {
        controller.openUrl("http://www.google.com");
        WebElement input = uiController.getPage().getWebElement("INPUT");
        input.click(); // will throw exception after first scenario
    }

}
```

Scenarios

```
Scenario: Works
    Whatever

Scenario: DoesNotWork
    Whatever
```

I would like to understand how to pass an arguement into te StepDefintion classes and not re-instantiate it every time.
I would like to retrieve the PageFactory WebElements without calling getter methods

Comment: The combination of [@Before hooks](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#before) and [dependency injection](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/state/#dependency-injection) to create your WebDriver and then pass it around to your step definitions should give you what you need.

Comment: Relating to dependency injection: [Sharing state between steps in Cucumber-JVM using PicoContainer](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer).